# Summing values from JSON end point based on category

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have a [JSON end point](https://opendata.howardcountymd.gov/resource/ghg6-4crr.json) for projects in a county. I am able to call a list of any of the object properties. What I want to do is to add together either all the values of `budget` property or the `spent_encumbered` by the value of `category` property.

For example, the total cost of all the projects that were for bridges, general county projects, school systems projects, etc.

Ideas I've had:

- Return all the values of the category property
- Push them all to an array
- Do an if statement, `if data[i].category === "school system projects"` // or whatever array value?
- `For loop` to add up all the returned budget values for the specific category.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're sending all this data over the wire for the client to crunch rather than doing it on the server side?

Comment: It's not my data, I'm getting it from a county. Also, this is for learning not just how to call data via an API but manipulate it and also to practice using objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is some sort of a filter/map/reduce.  Fortunately, JavaScript with modern browsers provides exactly that.

Using jQuery to get the data:

```
$.getJSON('https://opendata.howardcountymd.gov/resource/ghg6-4crr.json', 
           function( data) { cityData = data });
```

This returns a nice array with all the objects already parsed.  Once you've gotten the data, you can run this through a filter, for example:

```
var filteredArray = cityData.filter(
  function(value) {
      return value.fiscal_year='2015' && typeof value.spent_encumbered !== 'undefined'
  }
)
```

This can then be reduced into a single number - for example:

```
var total_spent_encumbered = 
  filteredArray.reduce(
    function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) { 
       return previousValue + Number(currentValue.spent_encumbered) }, 0
  );
```

You can of course, combine all these functions and externalize the filter and reduce internal functions to allow you to mix and match both, giving you a lot of flexibility.

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kptnmLmL/)

Comment: I'm new to using `$.getJSON`, forgive me if I am missing something obvious, but using `$(document).ready(function () {
    var cityData = {};
    $.getJSON('https://opendata.howardcountymd.gov/resource/ghg6-4crr.json',

    function (data) {
        cityData = data
    });
    console.log(cityData);
});` I do not get any returned data

Comment: yeah, that is tricky.  When jQuery is getting data from a remote source, the call is asynchronous.  You have to wait for the data to be returned.   If you did this: $(document).ready(function () { var cityData = {}; $.getJSON('https://opendata.howardcountymd.gov/resource/ghg6-4crr.json', function (data) { cityData = data; console.log(cityData); });  });  You should see the data

Comment: Put the `console.log` in the function, got it! Sorry to keep bugging you with this but I am trying to work my way through your example. I'm using jsfiddle (only thing I have access to right now) and it's telling me that `cityData.filter` is not a function. Is that because of jsfiddle's limitations or something else? I also tried by adding in `var filteredArray = [];` at the beginning.

Comment: I've added in a link to a working version on jsFiddle